# Save a rendered page as a XAML file

Tags: wpf, xaml, file, save

In a WPF application, how can I save a dynamically rendered page as a new XAML file?

Answer (score 3):

Use the [XamlWriter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.markup.xamlwriter.aspx) to convert an object to XAML.

```
string xaml = XamlWriter.Save(page)
```

or

```
XamlWriter.Save(page, stream)
```

Where `page` is your dynamically rendered page object.

Comment: That's close but that only gets me the XAML code, it does not get me the dynamic, rendered result with the filled datagrid and what-not

Comment: @Jim: you should go back and modify your question to include all the requirements, instead of waiting for people to answer before saying "nah, that's not what i want".

Comment: Please go back and read the question. It clearly states that I'm looking for the dynamically rendered result of the XAML. There is absolutely no difference between my original question and the comment above.